# What does __memcpy_ssse3_back function do?

Tags: performance, udp, memcpy, perf

I use perf to analyse my code , function __memcpy_ssse3_back() costs most (about 7%), the second is function copy_user_enhanced_fast_string(), what do these two functions do, is it because of udp_recv?

Thanks very much!

Comment: It is not clear from this question. You would have to show us your code. Backtrace to the function would be also useful. Basically is *some* optimized for x86_64 `memcpy`. `opy_user_enhanced_fast_string` is kernel function, but again without the context it is hard to guess.

Comment: They are Linux functions.  Most important thing to know when you profile code is to know when you're done.  Unless you want to improve Linux, you can conclude that you're done.